# Getting 401 Unauthorized error on file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, httpwebrequest

I have an asp.net application that submits files to a sharepoint document library.
Each time it tries to submit I get a

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Here is the c# code

```
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                    postedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);


                    Uri address = new Uri(url);
                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
                    request.Method = "POST";

                    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                    request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
                    request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", dvalue);
                    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    request.ContentLength = length;
                    using (Stream postSTream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        postSTream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    }
```

This works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it to our test environment, it raises the 401 error. IIS is configured for anonymous authentication. I think it is something to do with the file upload? Any insight or thoughts are appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You have enabled anonymous authentication which is working as intended, but the action you are trying to perform may be unauthorized. This may help - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Does that only relate to web api though? I'm not really using MVC. This is just being called on a button click

Comment: Not sure mate, just wanted to highlight that authorization and authentication are 2 separate things. It could possibly be related to folder permissions. Check the answer in http://forums.asp.net/t/1165237.aspx as it may be helpful (particularly the sub codes and permissions).

Answer (score 0):

You should give write folder permission to the applicaion pool user account.

Comment: I'ved tried it. the service account has full control to the document library